# How to checked the checkbox if mouse is clicked on label

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have one label name as lblName and one checkbox name as chkId. if I click on lblName then i want the value of chkId should be checked . For that I am using the following code but its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

$("[#name]").click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr("chkId")).prop('checked',      
 function(i, oldVal) { return !oldVal; });
});

});
</script>
</head>

 <body>
<label id="lblName" runat= "server">Name</label>
<asp:CheckBox ID="="chkId" runat="server"/></body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use the **for** attribute of the label to do that. you don't have to go for javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any javascript for this - put the checkbox inside the `label` element. The browser will then put the check in the control when the label itself is clicked.

```
<label id="lblName" runat= "server">
    Name
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkId" runat="server"/>
</label>
```

Also, there appears to be a lot of syntax errors in your example - are these just typos?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need javascript for this feature. Try this:

```
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="CheckBox1" runat="server">Name</asp:Label>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have an error here :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="="chkId" runat="server"/></body>
```

delete the `="`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#lblName").click(function() {
    $('#chkId').prop('checked',true);
});

});

</script>
```